# Handling Multiple AJAX Callbacks with Unique Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I'm using JQuery's implementation of AJAX to access multiple JSON and different URLS. I have an array of names that each URL corresponds to, and would like to be able to reference the corresponding name that goes with the corresponding JSON file in the callback funciton of the AJAX request.

I've written a sample of my code so far for testing:

```
    var nameList = ['Tom', 'Neil', 'Jane']; 
    for(var i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++){
        var currentName = nameList[i]; 
        var newURL = urlFromName(currentName)
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: newURL,
            dataype: 'jsonp'
        }).always(function(data,status, error){
               console.log(currentName);
               console.log(data);
           });
    }
```

The code outputs:

```
      - Neil
      - Object 
      - Neil
      - Object
      - Neil
      - Object
```

I am looking for each Object to be printed out with the corresponding name from the nameList that I have supplied it. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You didn't bind the value of currentName to the always callback. It should also print "Jane" 3 times instead of "Neil" is there an obscure off-by-one error?

Comment: first, what Frits said, you need a function inside your for loop or some other binding for currentName. Also, try JSON.stringify for friendlier output of the data object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var nameList = ['Tom', 'Neil', 'Jane']; 
    for(var i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++){
        var currentName = nameList[i]; 
        var newURL = urlFromName(currentName)
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: newURL,
            dataype: 'jsonp',
            currentName: currentName // <-- Add this here
        }).always(function(data,status, error){
               console.log(this.currentName); // <-- Use the 'this' to get it
               console.log(data);
           });
    }
```